# Modifying StereoVision 1.0.0 Library cp27 to crop video INSIDE of class: Error, Tuple Indices must be Ints

Tags: python, class, opencv, tuples, typeerror

Python 2.7.14

OpenCv 3.1.0

IDE: Eclipse Neon 3 used as editor but command prompt to run do to the arg parse

Background: First I would like to state that I am a mechanical engineer so I have very little programming exp.  I have an issue using the Stereovision Library/Modules to run my stereo cam because I have a stereo camera with a chipset that stitches the left and right images side by side and sends them into the PC via a single USB.

Currently: Tracing this problem to reading the devices into a left and right image, I found the class it creates "StereoPair" needs to be modified (at least to start) to read in a single feed and crop it into two individual feeds.  I am trying to modify the class to crop it but I am not familiar with class rules well enough to follow what is wrong with this code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from stereovision.point_cloud import PointCloud


class StereoPair(object):

"""
A stereo pair of cameras.

This class allows both cameras in a stereo pair to be accessed
simultaneously. It also allows the user to show single frames or videos
captured online with the cameras. It should be instantiated with a context
manager to ensure that the cameras are freed properly after use.
"""

#: Window names for showing captured frame from each camera
windows = ["{} camera".format(side) for side in ("Left", "Right")]

def __init__(self, devices):
    """
    Initialize cameras.

    ``devices`` is an iterable containing the device numbers.
    """
    #: Video captures associated with the ``StereoPair``
    self.captures = [cv2.VideoCapture(device) for device in devices]

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    for capture in self.captures:
        capture.release()
    for window in self.windows:
        cv2.destroyWindow(window)

def get_frames(self):
    """Get current frames from cameras."""
    for capture in self.captures:
        wid = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        hei = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        x_1 = int(0)
        y_1 = int(0)
        x_2 = int(wid/2)
        y_2 = int(hei)
        readinto = capture.read()
        croprt = int(readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2])
        croplft = int(readinto[y_1:y_2, x_2:wid])
        return [croprt, croplft]

def show_frames(self, wait=0):
    """
    Show current frames from cameras.

    ``wait`` is the wait interval in milliseconds before the window closes.
    """
    for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
        cv2.imshow(window[1], croprt[1])
        cv2.imshow(window[1], croptlft[1])
    cv2.waitKey(wait)

def show_videos(self):
    """Show video from cameras."""
    while True:
        self.show_frames(1)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

That is the code I modified from the Stereovision Library 1.0.0
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/StereoVision/1.0.0

The size of the camera pixels would be an even number and an integer.  Is there any reason I would be getting the error:

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

As you can see, I even tried adding int(variable) to every variable.  It even works with just the opencv library so this issue must be some class rule I'm not aware of or don't completely understand.  Here is a working display program I made:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    x1 = 0
    x2 = width/2
    y1 = 0
    y2 = height
    cropright = frame[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    cropleft = frame[y1:y2, x2:width]
# Our operations on the frame come here
# Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('cropright',cropright)
    cv2.imshow('cropleft',cropleft)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've read many other tuple error posts and none helped.  I tried adding a np.array([data], dtype=object) and that didn't work either.  If anyone can help or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

UPDATE:
Here is the entire Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_webcams", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "show_webcams", line 50, in main
    pair.show_videos()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\stereovision\stereo_cameras.py", line 98,
in show_videos
    self.show_frames(1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\stereovision\stereo_cameras.py", line 90,
in show_frames
    for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\stereovision\stereo_cameras.py", line 80,
in get_frames
    croprt = int(readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

UPDATE 2:

Adding the original code which I modified from the working library.

```
def __init__(self, devices):
    """
    Initialize cameras.

    ``devices`` is an iterable containing the device numbers.
    """
    #: Video captures associated with the ``StereoPair``
    self.captures = [cv2.VideoCapture(device) for device in devices]

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    for capture in self.captures:
        capture.release()
    for window in self.windows:
        cv2.destroyWindow(window)

def get_frames(self):
    """Get current frames from cameras."""
    return [capture.read()[1] for capture in self.captures]

def show_frames(self, wait=0):
    """
    Show current frames from cameras.

    ``wait`` is the wait interval in milliseconds before the window closes.
    """
    for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
        cv2.imshow(window, frame)
    cv2.waitKey(wait)

def show_videos(self):
    """Show video from cameras."""
    while True:
        self.show_frames(1)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

UPDATE 3:
Adding frame[window][0] for croprt.  Updated as follows.

```
def get_frames(self):
        """Get current frames from cameras."""
        for capture in self.captures:
            wid = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
            hei = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
            x_1 = int(0)
            y_1 = int(0)
            x_2 = int(wid/2)
            y_2 = int(hei)
            readinto = capture.read()
            croprt = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2]
            croplft = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_2:wid]
            return [croprt, croplft]

    def show_frames(self, wait=0):
        """
        Show current frames from cameras.

        ``wait`` is the wait interval in milliseconds before the window closes.
        """
        for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
            cv2.imshow(frame[window][0], croprt[1])
            cv2.imshow(frame[window][1], croptlft[1])
        cv2.waitKey(wait)
```

This returns the identical traceback as the first.

UPDATE 3.1:

Misunderstood change and corrected this section:

```
def show_frames(self, wait=0):
    """
    Show current frames from cameras.

    ``wait`` is the wait interval in milliseconds before the window closes.
    """
    for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
        cv2.imshow(window, frame[window][0])
        cv2.imshow(window, frame[window][1])
    cv2.waitKey(wait)
```

Puts out the same traceback.

UPDATE 4:
TIME: 7:30 PM on 10/27/17

I only modified placement of the `print(window)` so that it can make an output. 
 There isn't a place for print(frames) to add to the code since it never gets through get_frames.  Purpose of this update is to add traceback for the following code:

```
def get_frames(self):
    """Get current frames from cameras."""
    for capture in self.captures:
        wid = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        hei = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        x_1 = int(0)
        y_1 = int(0)
        x_2 = int(wid/2)
        y_2 = int(hei)
        readinto = capture.read()
        croprt = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2]
        croplft = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_2:wid]
        return [croprt, croplft]

def show_frames(self, wait=0):
    """
    Show current frames from cameras.

    ``wait`` is the wait interval in milliseconds before the window closes.
    """
    print(self.windows)
    for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
        print(self.frames)
        cv2.imshow(window, frame[window][0])
        cv2.imshow(window, frame[window][1])
    cv2.waitKey(wait)

def show_videos(self):
    """Show video from cameras."""
    while True:
        self.show_frames(1)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

Traceback:

```
['Left camera', 'Right camera']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show_webcams", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "show_webcams", line 50, in main
    pair.show_videos()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\stereovision\stereo_cameras.py", line 100,
 in show_videos
    self.show_frames(1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\stereovision\stereo_cameras.py", line 91,
in show_frames
    for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\stereovision\stereo_cameras.py", line 80,
in get_frames
    croprt = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

There isn't any different in the error output from the code besides the print of windows.

UPDATE FINAL:

Code is working with some debugging work.  It seems that when I created the `capture.read` for `readinto`, it needs to create 2 things for the array.  One is the numpy array matrix full of ints (I think) and the other is a list of booleans (that consists of  returns true for this).  So the biggest change is the addition of `ret` to the code next to `readinto.`

```
def get_frames(self):
        """Get current frames from cameras."""
        for capture in self.captures:
            wid = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
            hei = int(capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
            x_1 = 0
            y_1 = 0
            x_2 = wid/2
            y_2 = hei
            ret, readinto = capture.read()
            croprt = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2]
            croplft = readinto[y_1:y_2, x_2:wid]
            return [croprt, croplft]

    def show_frames(self, wait=0):
        """
        Show current frames from cameras.

        ``wait`` is the wait interval in milliseconds before the window closes.
        """
        print(self.windows)
        for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames()):
            cv2.imshow(window, frame)
            #cv2.imshow(window, frame[window][1])
        cv2.waitKey(wait)
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback. What does `readinto` do? does it return a tuple?

Comment: I just updated this to include the traceback.  Yes it returns a tuple.  readinto reads in capture file so it can be cropped.  It's pretty similar to the original Stereovision library.  I will add the original after I post this.  (original works perfectly but left and right images obviously don't come out cropped).

Comment: ok looking at this a bit more: `get_frames()` returns an array of `cropleft, cropright`. `cropleft` and `cropright` are each a tuple. then you `for window, frame in zip(self.windows, self.get_frames())`. You probably wanted to refer to `frame[window][0]` for cropleft in that section?

Comment: anyway you can't `int()` a tuple. Remove the `int()` around `readinto` call and see where it's complaining about tuple in the original question.

Comment: I removed the int around the 'croprt' and 'croptlft' but left it for the vars defined.  I changed to the 'frame[window][0]' but it didn't change the traceback.  I updated (update 3) the code above to show you and confirm that is what you meant.  Since I put 'croprt' and 'croptlft' in that order I put the 0 in front of the 'croprt' instead of croplft.  You are correct.

Comment: Sorry I might have misunderstood your comment and just realized it.  I tried it again with Update 3.1's code and got the same traceback also.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify you are using the code in "Update 2" now and no longer using `croprt = int(readinto[y_1:y_2, x_1:x_2])` ?

Comment: Inside `show_frames()` can you print `window` and `frame` in your `zip(...)` comprehension? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, update 2 was yesterday.  I've run both, but I'm currently trying to work with the update 3.1 code.  Neither Update 2 or 3 worked.  I will try to add the print now.

Comment: I was trying the print frame and window and started trying to follow why it doesn't output and just realized.  The print window and frame shouldn't output because the class would set them up for a result of get_frames but that is where it returns a tuple error and does not continue.

Comment: the error now shows up in `get_frames()` and not `show_frames`?! Please update the traceback because the one you have posted still says `int(...)`

Comment: The error has always showed up inside the get_frames and cannot get past the `croprt`.  The show_frames line that starts with `for` accesses that function.   Update 4 has what you requested.

Comment: I found a solution.  I fixed the code and it is running.  I will update this tomorrow to show my final code that works, but don't waste anymore time tonight worrying about this.

Comment: I updated it.  The big change is the addition of ret for the capture.read.  It needs a list of boolean values in a separate output.  The numpy array then came out correctly for readinto.  With some minor edits, that fixed everything.  If someone could explain why or how this opencv function works for sure, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Also, If you think I should modify the title to include some other error read for the users, let me know.  I just don't even know what to call this error, really.